# How to declare stored firebase variable in arraylist?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Don't get the wish result with getting data in firebase, only get one variable in a table

[image]

In my Code...

```
 databaseReference.child(fecha).child(String.valueOf(c)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                          if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                              //RowPosition rp = dataSnapshot.getValue(RowPosition.class);
                              //myResult.add(rp);
                              for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                  RowPosition rp = snap.getValue(RowPosition.class);
                                  myResult.add(rp);
                              }

                              for (RowPosition row : myResult){
                                  Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(row.getRowposition()));
                              }



                          }else{//BOOLEAN
                              //showToast("NO TIENE");
                              addMedicion();

                          }
```

In RowPosition.class

[image]

In Logcat view the result...

[image]

Gratefull for your coments and methods

Comment: You can query your database by using orderByChild("rowposition");  [Learn More](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

Comment: You can combine both for loops

Comment: I find the solution, see in bot on this page

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `referenceToA` is a reference to node `A` in your JSON, you can get just `rowposition` between `0` and `1` with:

```
referenceToA.orderByChild("rowposition").startAt(0).endAt(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

Have a look at the [Firebase document on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your response, my idea is charge the data (rowposition)in a array and this compare with the row in put the data for throw if exist the position or not in the database

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for this problem, Firebase always retrieve all data to the child, with hashmap retrieve specific data

***the code.***

```
 databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                                Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                Log.e("TAG","Row " + newPost.get("rowposition"));
```

***Result.***

[image]

I will hope helping any